# In Perl, is there any harm in creating a subroutine with the same name as a package?

Tags: perl, syntax, constructor

Say I have a package called `My::Pkg`, and that package has a `->new(...)` class method to instantiate new objects:

```
package My::Pkg;

sub new {bless {@_[1..$#_]} => $_[0]}
```

Is there any harm in defining the following subroutine:

```
sub My::Pkg {@_ ? My::Pkg::new('My::Pkg', @_) : 'My::Pkg'}
```

So that someone could write:

```
my $obj = My::Pkg one => 1, two => 2;
```

Rather than:

```
my $obj = My::Pkg->new(one => 1, two => 2); # which still works, but is longer
```

I like the terseness of the package-named-constructor-subroutine method, but I am interested to know if there are any hidden gotchas to this technique that I have not thought of.

---

Update:

Inheritance works correctly, as shown by the example here:

```
{package a; sub new {say "a::new [@_] ", $_[0]->init}}
{package b;    our @ISA = 'a'; sub init {"(b::init [@_])"}}
{package a::b; our @ISA = 'b';}

sub a::b {print "absub [@_], "; 'a::b'}

# a::b() called with no args, returns 'a::b', which then becomes 'a::b'->new(...)
a::b->new;            # absub [], a::new [a::b] (b::init [a::b])
a::b->new(1, 2, 3);   # absub [], a::new [a::b 1 2 3] (b::init [a::b])    

# no call to `a::b()` but otherwise the same:
'a::b'->new;          # a::new [a::b] (b::init [a::b])
'a::b'->new(1, 2, 3); # a::new [a::b 1 2 3] (b::init [a::b])

new a::b::;           # a::new [a::b] (b::init [a::b])
new a::b:: 1, 2, 3;   # a::new [a::b 1 2 3] (b::init [a::b])
```

Interestingly the only thing so far that is different is that the following 2 lines become syntax errors:

```
new a::b;
new a::b 1, 2, 3;
```

Which is a syntax error for the same reason `some_undefined_sub some_defined_sub;` is one.

If the `new` subroutine is defined, it is parsed as `new( a::b(...) )` which is normal for two adjacent bareword subroutines.

Personally, I am ok with `new a::b` becoming a syntax error, the unambiguous version `new a::b::` will always work as *tchrist* helpfully points out below.

Comment: Seems clean. If something were to fail, it would be `some_sub My::Pkg a=>1,b=>2;`. It doesn't.

Comment: @ikegami:It most certainly **DOES** fail: `sub X::Y { die "X::Y() called\n" }
sub X::Y::new { warn "X::Y::new() called\n" }
sub new { die "main::new() called" }
$a = new X::Y "business";
warn "got $a";` will die because it calls `main::new(X::Y("business"))` as a subroutine instead of properly invoking `X::Y::new("X::Y", "business"))` as a method. Also, the subroutine call doesn’t respect inheritance as is considered mandatory in an OO world.

Comment: It is evil that `new X::Y "business"` suddenly means something different from `X::Y->new("business")` — *which* BTW actually now means `X::Y()->new("business")` instead of the `X::Y::new("X::Y", "business")` that everyone thinks it means.

Comment: @tchrist => look at the `sub My::Pkg` line above, when given no arguments as in the case of `X::Y->new("business")`, the subroutine always returns the string `'X::Y'`, which then makes the method call look like `'X::Y'->new("business")`.  So the method look-up is subject to normal inheritance, which in this case would end at `X::Y::new("X::Y", "business")`.

Answer (score 7):

That’s **precisely** why

```
$thingie = new Some::Class one => 1, two => 2;
```

or

```
$thingie = new Some::Class::
               one => 1,
               two => 2,
           ;
```

exists, so just use that.

But yes, I think you will get yourself into a whole slew of troubles, since I am the only person in the world who bothers to package-quote. I don’t have time right now to dig through my old problem-testing code, but I am pretty sure this will eventually make you cry if you go down the road you’re speaking of.

Comment: I would have thought that indirect object syntax would result in more ambiguities than this technique.  With this method, the identifier `My::Pkg` always means `&My::Pkg()` unless it is in glob context, where it is the string.  I'd be interested to know of any corner cases where this does not hold.

Comment: There’s a huge difference between method invoking a method and calling a subroutine: **inheritance**.  By not using method calls, you’re breaking with OO design. Perl has all kinds of weirdness so that `Some::Class` really means `"Some::Class"`, and that is what people are expecting it to do. If you create a function by the name of the package, you will completely hose yourself when trying to make class method calls, because you will call the dumb function instead.  And contrary to popular cargo-cult myth, there is absolutely nothing whatsoever ambiguous with `METHOD CLASS:: ARGLIST`.

Comment: See the update to the question above, inheritance works fine.

Answer (score 4):

"I am interested to know if there are any hidden gotchas to this technique that I have not thought of."

I think a hidden gotcha is lack of consistency with how most OOP langs define constructors.  Obviously, Perl likes its TMTOWTDI philosophy, but someone having to maintain your code later when/if you're not around may take more time to understand what your code is doing.

Also, what if you want to add another constructor?  I've seen some classes where there are constructors named:  new, new_from_file, etc.  Maybe not the best design, but it did clarify that an object was constructed in a unique way.